# C# WebBrowser control not displaying custom HTML

Tags: c#

I have a web browser control that for some reason isn't loading my HTML:

```
 string updatingChatHTML = ""
        + "<HTML>    "
        + "<head>"
        + "<style>"
        + "body {"
        + "  margin: 0px;"
        + "  padding: 0px;"
        + "  background: " + chatBackground + ";\n"
        + "  Font-Family: Arial;"
        + "  font-size: 11px; "
        + "  text-align: left;"
        + "}"
        + "</style>"
        + "</head>"
        + "<body>";
txtChat.DocumentText = updatingChatHTML + "</body></HTML>";
```

(txtChat is my WebBrowser Control).

The weird thing is, it was working before I changed something, but I can't figure out what I changed that caused it to stop working.

I have a breakpoint set to just after the last line above, and I can see that updatingChatHTML has the proper value it's meant to, but txtChat.DocumentText still has a value of `<HTML></HTML>\0`.

I thought maybe it was an initialisation thing, so I added `txtChat.Navigate("about:blank");` prior to any assignment, but it still doesn't work.

This event actually gets fired quite often though, and the first time/two times, it doesn't work, but after the form is finished loading it seems to, but it's already the last thing to happen on my Form_Load.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attempting to set the `DocumentText` property when

- no document is loaded
- or the browser control is not in a ready state (e.g. currently loading a document)

will cause the property assignment to fail silently.

After calling the `Navigate` function you should monitor the `DocumentCompleted` event for notification of when the navigation operation completes.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping this wasn't the case but it was. I already had a lot of code in my `DocumentCompleted` event and didn't want to have to butcher it, so I essentially added in a check for if the path was `blank` (which incidentally is what shows when you navigate to `about:blank`) and to then fire the above code, styling the page. Will accept your answer when I can in a few minutes.